# How to get String from C# with \r to JavaScript variable?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I write program with aspx and C# in VS2010.
I want to alert all the SoftWareNotes in loop. (it's a varchar value in my DB).
so I did that:

```
<% for(Software s in Db.Softwares){ %>
<script>
            var GetTextArea= '<%=s.SoftwareNotes%>' ;
            alert(GetTextArea);
</script>
<%}%>
```

and it's work fine , until that SoftwareNotes contain /r . for example in this string:
"fdbdfb\r\ndfbdf\r\ndfb" (from the debugger) , it's not print nothing, and continue to the next one.

**Why and how can I fix that?**

*The field SoftwareNotes contain /r cause it's populate by TextAreas ..so if someone make enter it save it like a /r.

---

edit 2:20:
I found one solution , but it's not the best.. 
I write this code above the code before:

```
 <%
                String tryRemoveNL="";
                if(s.SoftwareNotes!=null)
                    tryRemoveNL= Regex.Replace(s.SoftwareNotes, @"\r\n?|\n", " ");
                 %>
```

and now when I write:

```
var GetTextArea= '<%=tryRemoveNL%>' ;
```

it works. but I want to keep the newLines.. maybe you have other solutions?

Comment: Which browser is this for? Running your example `alert("fdbdfb\r\ndfbdf\r\ndfb")` in Chrome and IE 10 shows the alert with line breaks, no problem.

Comment: Google Chrome , but tried in IE too. 
maybe the problem from casting this variable from C# to js? (but without the /r that work fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do it using the following:

```
var GetTextArea= '<%=s.SoftwareNotes.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\r\\n"))%>' ;
alert(GetTextArea);
```

This keeps the line breaks within the alert message.

The issue was because the literal linebreaks were coming through into the javascript, creating *invalid syntax*, similar to:

```
var GetTextArea = 'fdbdfb
dfbdf
dfb'; //Invalid syntax for multiline javascript string
```

So instead, this solution will write out:

```
var GetTextArea = 'fdbdfb\r\ndfbdf\r\ndfb'
```